# How to find all python installations on mac os x and uninstall all but the native OS X installation

Tags: python, macos, unix, pip

I have installed a few versions on my MacBook for different projects and have only now realized what a mistake that was. I have used homebrew to install it, installed it via python's website (`Python 2.7.8 Mac OS X 64-bit/32-bit x86-64/i386 Installer (for Mac OS X 10.6 and later [2])`) and other ways I may not remember. I am running 10.9.4 OS X.

**I am wondering how I can find the location of all python installations on my computer and delete everything and packages that depend on them *except* the native one.** I'd like to essentially start from scratch without reinstalling my OS.

*Also, I am wondering if I can apply the same method to find all `pip` related files.*

***Update***:

`which -a python` gives me all the paths to each executable python. Is it normal to have multiple ones?

```
╭─ishaantaylor@Ishaans-MacBook-Pro.local ~
╰─➤  which -a python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin//python
/usr/bin//python
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: you can start by removing any Python Frameworks in `/Library/Frameworks` and any User Library (like `~/Library/Frameworks`). The system one is in `/System/Library/Frameworks`.

Comment: @BradAllred what installation is in `usr/bin/` and which is in `usr/local/bin`?

Comment: those aren't installed as part of the system if that is what you are asking. your homebrew install would be one or both of those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What version of Python is on my Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33175827/what-version-of-python-is-on-my-mac)

Comment: If you are coming here with Monterey 12.3 (or newer, I guess, as I can't see the future).  [There is no longer a system python installation.](https://macmule.com/2022/01/29/macos-monterey-12-3-will-remove-python-2-7-usr-bin-python/)

Answer (score 47):

It's normal to have many `python` binaries. You can see which is which in `/usr/bin` with this command:

`$ ls -l /usr/bin/python*`

You will see several links to different places. The *native* `python` is that one, which is in the `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/`. Note that for OSX 10.9 (and for everything at least until 10.13) this is the `python2`, not `python3`. So you can safely remove all the other versions.

What are the other versions which you may have?

- Something downloaded from the official site [python.org](https://python.org/downloads). It is located in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/`. You can remove whatever in this folder you do not want. Removing the whole folder will completely remove Python including the original system version.
- [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) distribution is by default located in `/Users/your_user/anaconda3/`, but of course you may put in the other place. But if it contains `anaconda` in the path – it's Anaconda distribution. You may remove this folder.
- Either `homebrew` or `port` versions are in `/opt/local/bin/`. See the link destination with `$ ls -l /opt/local/bin/python*`. The best way of removing this is to use built-in commands like *uninstall*.
- Some packages might be in `~/Library/Python/` - that's from `pip`. You may safely remove the entire content of this folder in order to have a *"clean"* `python`.
- Finally, after you removed all the other versions, do not forget to remove the broken links to binaries, if there are still any.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52123490/4222580).

Comment: Thanks @Yury Kirienko , I was having this problem and this helped

Comment: Homebrew actually installs symlinks in `/usr/local/bin/`. Maybe that's a change, but there I just found 4 different python versions...

Comment: Using `sudo uninstall python311` tells me it will break dependencies... am I about to regret following these instructions?

Comment: Um, you should have made it clearer that deleting `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/` will remove the original system python too!

Comment: Besides which, these instructions appear incomplete. "remove the broken links to binaries"? I've stared hard at my command line and yelled, "Broken links to binaries, BEGONE!" three times now, and it's still looking for the version of python I removed. There is apparently more detail that is missing.

Answer (score 8):

you can start by removing any Python Frameworks in `/Library/Frameworks` and any User Library (like `~/Library/Frameworks`). The system one is in `/System/Library/Frameworks`.

homebrew and macports install under `/usr` somewhere IIRC. not sure of other places to look, but you should be able to grep for "Python" to find them all.

be aware, if you have installed *other* software via homebrew that is dependent on Python, you will break it. you may be able to fix it with symbolic links to the system python, however, some software requires Python 3. as of 10.9 the system has Python 2.3-2.7 only.

Comment: ls -la /usr/bin/pyt* should show you where all python installations are located, since /usr/bin contains just sym links...

Comment: macports installs your python into the /opt/local/bin/python folder