# What version of Python is on my Mac?

Tags: python, macos

I have a mac, when I do:

```
python --version
```

I got:

```
Python 2.7.6
```

but when I got to:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3
```

where is 2.7.6 located ?
any advice what should I do?

UPDATE:

```
$ which -a python python3
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python3

$ brew list python python3
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/python

$ locate python

WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:



sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.
```

in PyCharm editor, the default settings interpreter shows:

[image]

Comment: `which python` ...

Comment: I did : sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist  but when I do locate python I always get the same WARNING.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You could have multiple Python versions on your macOS.

You may check that by `command`, `type` or `which` command, like:

```
which -a python python2 python2.7 python3 python3.6
```

Or type `python` in *Terminal* and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> few times for auto completion, which is equivalent to:

```
compgen -c python
```

By default `python`/`pip` commands points to the first binary found in `PATH` environment variable depending what's actually installed. So before installing Python packages with Homebrew, the default Python is installed in `/usr/bin` which is shipped with your macOS (e.g. Python 2.7.10 on High Sierra). Any versions found in `/usr/local` (such as `/usr/local/bin`) are provided by external packages.

It is generally advised, that when working with multiple versions, for Python 2 you may use `python2`/`pip2` command, respectively for Python 3 you can use `python3`/`pip3`, but it depends on your configuration which commands are available.

It is also worth to mention, that since [release of Homebrew 1.5.0+](https://brew.sh/2018/01/19/homebrew-1.5.0/) (on 19 January 2018), the `python` formula has been upgraded to Python 3.x and a `python@2` formula will be added for installing Python 2.7. Before, `python` formula was pointing to Python 2.

For instance, if you've installed different version via Homebrew, try the following command:

```
brew list python python3
```

or:

```
brew list | grep ^python
```

it'll show you all Python files installed with the package.

Alternatively you may use `apropos` or `locate python` command to locate more Python related files.

To check any environment variables related to Python, run:

```
env | grep ^PYTHON
```

---

To address your issues:

- > Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/python

  Means you don't have Python installed via Homebrew. However double check by specifying only one package at a time (like `brew list python python2 python3`).
- > The locate database (`/var/db/locate.database`) does not exist.

  Follow the advice and run:

  ```
  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist
  ```

  After the database is rebuild, you can use `locate` command.

Answer (score 47):

To check third version, we can use,

```
python3 --version
```

To install python on macOS, we need to install command line developer tools. From Catalina, python is removed from OS bundle.  For more information, [Apple Official](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652014) and [Python Official](https://python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/starting/install3/osx.html).

Comment: This command opens stupid macOS install python window from xcode. Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Currently from Catalina, Python is not comes from OS, Alex. We've to install it command line developer tools. Sadly, it will install all the additional tools as well! [Apple Official](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652014) and [Python Official](https://python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/starting/install3/osx.html)

Answer (score 13):

Use below command to see all python installations :

```
which -a python
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `which command`. It will show you the path

```
which python
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [docs regarding Python on Mac](https://docs.python.org/2/using/mac.html#getting-and-installing-macpython).

The version at /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework is installed by Apple and is used by the system. It is version 3.3 in your case. You can access and use this Python interpreter, but you shouldn't try to remove it, and it may not be the one that comes up when you type "Python" in a terminal or click on an icon to launch it.

You must have installed another version of Python (2.7) on your own at some point, and now that is the one that is launched by default.

As other answers have pointed out, you can use the command `which python` on your terminal to find the path to this other installation.

Answer (score 0):

Just type `python` and then hit `tab-button` You will get the list of all the python available in your os

Comment: this relies on the autocomplete feature of `zsh`