# Location for Python version on macOS (using universal-installer for 3.10.5)

Tags: python, macos, installation, path

My very first post here, as new comer to MacOS and Python.

Recently installed python `3.10.5` via `macOS 64-bit universal2 installer` .pkg file downloaded from [python.org > Downloads > mac OS](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3105/) on MacOS 12.4 [M1/Apple Silicon].

In terminal, the command `python3` shows the version as `3.10.5`.

But `echo $PATH` is giving me a path leading to

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/**3.10**/bin

I was expecting a folder for the installed Python version with equal name `3.10.5`, however there seems to be no such folder.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Good first question! I refined the formatting (including a link) and formulated a concrete question as I read it (please correct me by [edit]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** `3.10` (major.minor) points already to the latest installed patch-version (`5` here). Also recommend to use the `Current` folder for the PATH environment-variable like below.

#### From command to binary location

Assume

- `python3` is the command
- after running `python3 --version` its version shows as `3.10.5`

See also: [How to Check Your Python Version | LearnPython.com](https://learnpython.com/blog/check-python-version/)

Then this command shows the **location of the binary** for command `python3`:

`which python3`

See also: [python location on mac osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819661/python-location-on-mac-osx), [What version of Python is on my Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33175827/what-version-of-python-is-on-my-mac)

#### Apple's Framework convention

The Python installer follows the [Framework Versions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/VersionInformation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002255-BCIECADD) explained in Apple's *Framework Developer Guide*:

Frameworks (like Python instead `<Name>`) installed by convention in folder:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/<Name>.framework/Versions/<major>.<minor>/`

with following *version numbering-scheme*:

`<major>.<minor>` (like `3.10` for Python 3.10.5)

where `<major>` denotes the major-version (having breaking changes like `3` here) and `<minor>` denotes the minor-version (with only small feature-changes and bug-fixes, like `10` here). The  patch- or maintenance-version (like `5` here) is ignored in the folder-structure.

A recommended pattern for `PATH` environment-variable is to use macOS managed-frameworks' version-alias `Current` which points to the latest version installed for the framework. Try listing its contents to see the symbolic-link (also symlink or alias) with command `ls -l` followed by the path, for example:

```
/Library/ManagedFrameworks/Python/Python3.framework/Versions/Current/
```

See also: [macadmins/python: Framework files for use with popular python macadmin toolsets](https://github.com/macadmins/python)
and [symlink - How to get the fully resolved path of a symbolic link in Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4812/how-to-get-the-fully-resolved-path-of-a-symbolic-link-in-terminal)

#### Versioning Schemes

- Python versioning: [PEP 440 – Version Identification and Dependency Specification](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/)
- Wikipedia: [Software versioning (major, minor, patch)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning#Semantic_versioning)
- [Semantic Versioning (semver)](https://semver.org/)

Comment: Related article from Simon Willison (co-creator of Django): [Installing Python on macOS with the official Python installer](https://til.simonwillison.net/macos/python-installer-macos)

Comment: Thanks for that information. It helped me to clear up several misunderstandings i was having.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.10 is the major release. Python 3.10.5 is a maintenance release of 3.10 that replaces all previous 3.10 versions.

Comment: Thank you for your response Christof. Just to be clear, do we need to set or change any paths every time we perform a version update? Or is it only done for major releases?