# Find all python installations on system

Tags: python, bash, installation, terminal

Came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840961/how-to-find-all-python-installations-on-mac-os-x-and-uninstall-all-but-the-nativ)

**What I tried (followed advice from link above)**

**Command 1:**

```bash
which -a python*
```

**Output 1:**

```bash
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

**Command 2:**

```bash
which -a python3.9
```

**Output 2:**

```bash
/usr/local/bin/python3.9
```

**Conclusion**

- 'Output 2' was not contained in 'Output 1'
- therefore 'Command 1' did not completely fulfil its objective

**Help needed**

- I figured out how to match all 4 of the python installations with regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/FCb9mR/1)
- How do I use this inside of the `which -a <insert RegEx here>` command?

Comment: This would be equally applicable to tools that weren't Python- or programming-related at all. As such, [unix.se] is probably a better place for the question.

Comment: As a side node: `which -a` does not find all installations of a program on your computer, but finds all occurances of an executable within your PATH, which is slightly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find executables in all PATH directories

```
for p in $(echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'); do
    find "$p" -type f -executable -name 'python*'
done
```

Result

```
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python-argcomplete-check-easy-install-script-3.6
/usr/bin/python3.6m
/usr/bin/python3.11
/usr/bin/python3.6m-config
/usr/bin/python3.9
/usr/bin/python3.6
```

If regex is needed

```
find "$p" -type f -executable -regex '.*python.*'
```

to also find symbolic links

```
find "$p" -executable -regex '.*python.*' \( -type f -or -type l \)
```

Show binaries and symlinks

```
for p in $(echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'); do find "$p" -executable -regex '.*python[2-3][.0-9]*' \( -type f -or -type l \);done | xargs file -e elf | sort -t ':' -k 2
```

Result

```
/usr/bin/python2.7:  ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
/usr/bin/python3.6:  ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
/usr/bin/python3.9:  ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
/usr/bin/python3.11: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
/usr/bin/python2:    symbolic link to python2.7
/usr/bin/python3:    symbolic link to python3.6
```